# Restarting openerp enough number of times causes postgres to throw 'reached max column limit error'

Tags: postgresql, max, limit, openerp-7

Here's the scenario - Lets say I install a module which changes the column type of a table. And this module changes the type of the date_order field in sale_order table from date to datetime. Now what happens is everytime I restart openerp with updateall modules flag, it drops the original date_order column (with type date)  in the table and adds a new column date_order with type datetime.

Now postgres maintains a reference to all of its columns per table in pg_attribute table, which doesnt get cleared even when you drop the columns. Because of this every drop-column-add-column cycle that occurs when you restart openerp increments the column count for the table and in this case its the sale_order table. But the problem is postgres has a column limit of 1600 per table which will be reached if you restart openerp 800 times. And then openerp fails to start.

This is only in case of 1 column. If modules override multiple columns in the table, this limit will be reached sooner.

So the question is, is there a well known way to solve this problem with openerp?

My guess is this is not a very rare case scenario and some people may have already faced this problem. Are there any recommended solutions or conventions or best practices ?

Comment: Don't drop & recreate the column if it's already the right type?

Comment: `VACUUM FULL` the table?

Comment: @CraigRinger if the type is same it doesnt recreate the column. The problem is only when types are different

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko unfortunately VACUUM FULL doesn't clear the references to dropped column

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: pg_repack is an option: http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/ it essentially does an "online" drop & re-create of the table in the background so that would remove the ghost columns

Answer (score 0):

This is how we solved the problem:

Lets say there are two modules  sale_order, my_sale_order. Suppose my_sale_order extends the functionality of the sale_order.

And in my_sale_order you want to change the column type of a field in sale_order, lets say, change the type of column order_date from date to datetime. Now, instead of changing the type of order_date to datetime in my_sale_order, what you can do is add a new column called order_datetime  whose type is datetime in my_sale_order  and change all the references in UI markup(and any other references required for proper functioning) from order_date to order_datetime. You can also keep the order_date and order_datetime in sync in your code.

Btw there are a few solutions being discussed here :
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/restarting-openerp-enough-number-of-times-causes-postgres-to-throw-reached-max-column-limit-error-54511

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @sanfor added the solutions that we followed.